# How to find out what parameters/arguments a program is passing when it calls other programs?

Tags: terminal, parameters

I am using a program called **get_iplayer**, and during it's run, it calls other programs such as RMTPdump, flvstreamer and ffmpeg.

What I would like to find out is what information it is *passing* to these program. I can see on terminal that they have been called and they are working, but I can't see what they've been given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, use `strace` to log the `execve()` syscall.

```
strace -f -e execve -o iplayer-trace.log get_iplayer ...
```

On Windows, use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) – enable just the "Processes" category. *(Needs Administrator privileges.)*

On BSDs...edits would be welcome. It seems that `dtrace` is the usual way, at least in some of them:

```
dtrace -n 'proc:::exec-success { printf("%d %s", pid,curpsinfo->pr_psargs); }'
```